# How to provide the Default value to a boolean property when it was null

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

In the below code i am getting an exception because `"isValid"` is coming as `null` from the input request.

I want to set `"isValid"` to `"False"` when it was `null` from the input request.

Can anyone pls suggest me how i can do this ?

```
public class Details
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MessageInfo messageInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MessageInfo
{
    public bool isValid { get; set; }
}

var inputMessage =
{
    "Body":
    {
     "status":"success",
     "MessageInfo": 
      {
        "isValid":null
      }
    }
}

var messagebody = inputMessage.Body.ToObject<Details>();
```

Comment: This does not compile)

Comment: I have corrected the inputMessage now @GuruStron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
void Main()
{
    var inputMessage = "{ \"Body\":{\"status\":\"success\", \"MessageInfo\":{\"isValid\":null} }}";

   var inputMessageObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(inputMessage);
}
```

classes

```
public class Details
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public MessageInfo messageInfo { get; set; }
}


public class MessageInfo
{

    private bool? _isValid = false;
    public bool? IsValid
    {
        get { return _isValid; }
        set { _isValid = value == null ? false : value; }
    }
}

    public class Body
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public MessageInfo MessageInfo { get; set; }
    }

public class Root
{
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Newtonsoft.Json, use the [`NullValueHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_NullValueHandling.htm) property of the `JsonSerializer` class, [setting it to ignore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm). Then pass in this instance of `JsonSerializer` to an overload of the `ToObject<T>` function.

This tells serialization to ignore any properties that were null, leaving the property initialized to its default value.  (You can control that default value separately via [`System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=net-5.0) if you want.)

Fully compiling example below.  (The references to 'Body' were removed, to make it easier to focus on the main problem.)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var inputMessage = JToken.Parse(
            @"{
                ""status"":""success"",
                ""MessageInfo"": 
                {
                    ""isValid"":null
                }
            }");
            
            // build a custom serializer with a setting to ignore null
            var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(jsonSettings);

            // using the serializer with custom settings avoids the original exception
            var messagebody = inputMessage.ToObject<Details>(serializer);
        }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public MessageInfo messageInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class MessageInfo
    {
        public bool isValid { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the above solution you are ignoring the Null Value field but in my case when isValid is Null i want to assign the default value as "False".

Comment: The default value of a `bool` is already `false`, so technically you don't have to do anything else.  But if you want to explicitly set a default value, investigate the `DefaultValueAttribute` link in the answer.